# The file “MyApp” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it error (Xcode 11)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

I am currently developing an app using Xcode 11 and I am confused by the root of error message I am receiving when I try to build my app to run in the simulator. I have tried for hours to resolve this, using different tutorials I found on Stack Overflow but really haven't had any luck due to the fact most of the time these issues were reported for Xcode 11. The last time I had the software open, it ran totally fine so I'm very confused what changed since I last saved the project. If you can please help give some, that would be greatly appreciated. I have also attached an image of the error.

**What I Have Already Tried**

- Cleaned the build folder
- Manually cleaned the Derived Data folder
- Raised the permissions of the executable within Finder
- Check to make sure that the compiler is set to default in build options
- Checked the info.plist and updated the executable file to `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`
- Changed my derived data folder to another location
- Deleted manually added folders
- Restarted Xcode
- Restarted my computer

Image of error as it appears on Xcode:

[image]

Comment: What/where/where from - is the FOND file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's an iOS app, correct? With everything else you mentioned trying, there might be an issue with the simulator, so you could try running in a different simulator or resetting the current one to default settings. I've attached a screenshot and you can find this under the "Hardware" menu in the simulator. Note that it will delete all installed apps in the simulator.

[image: where to reset]

Comment: Thank you for your help and reply. I have tried this and still nothing :(  - Other projects run perfectly fine on the simulator but it sadly this project does not. If you have anymore solutions, I would greatly appreciate the help!